# Get Cellinfo for dual sim (Primary -physical sim and Secondary E-sim) Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, signal-strength, cellinfo, multisim

Background: As mentioned in the header, I use two sims (one physical and one Esim). Either one can be made primary sim as required by the user. Also, both the sims are active at the same time.

My app involves getting cellinfo and signal strength from the device.
I use [telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getAllCellInfo()) and [telephonyManager.getSignalStrength()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getSignalStrength()) to get the relevant data. But the data only comes in for primary sim.
Is there a way to get this data (cellinfo and signal strength objects) from both primary and secondary sims at the same time?

Additional Research:
Using [Subscription Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()), I was able to get some data like Phone number, MCC, MNC, Carrier name from both the sims at once.

Comment: I'm using Met monster core as a plugin in my flutter app.
how do you collect your data?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're using something like:
context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager?
to get the Telephony instance.

The above returned TelephonyManager will use the default subscription for the data you try to fetch.

As per Android docs:
To call an API for a specific subscription, use createForSubscriptionId(int).
e.g. telephonyManager = defaultSubTelephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subId);

So if you want to fetch the Telephony instance for a particular subscription, you need to know the subscriptionId for it.

You can fetch the subscriptionId list using SubscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList and for each subscriptionId create its own telephony instance.